# How to redirect to an anchor tag without having the page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to navigate to a section of the same page using anchor tags without having the page refresh because I have a form that would lose data if the page refreshes.

For some reason, when searching for this question, all of the answers seem to address everything but this specific issue. I don't have a reference whether this can be done in pure HTML, Javascript, or JQuery or even using anchor tags. I would just like the ability to scroll to a section of the same page without having to refresh.

Page code:

```
<div>

<a href="#faq">Link Test</a>


stuff here


<section id="faq">
</section>


</div>
```

**Update**
It seems like what I was looking for was scrollIntoView() and not an anchor tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How redirect page without refreshing main page after ajax success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300959/how-redirect-page-without-refreshing-main-page-after-ajax-success-function)

Comment: Your code seems fine at first glance

Answer (score 1):

To get this affect you need to use AJAX request. When get response you can append or replace some element in current page. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300959/how-redirect-page-without-refreshing-main-page-after-ajax-success-function), or [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get)
as examples.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with an anchor tag:

```html
<div>

<a href="#contentId">Link to some content</a>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae elit ultrices, ornare metus ac, vehicula magna. Morbi sem metus, vulputate sit amet nunc at, aliquet luctus nisl. Pellentesque congue commodo turpis non luctus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi sed velit et nibh congue faucibus. Suspendisse dapibus leo eget nisl tincidunt placerat. Sed gravida ante quis erat tincidunt, nec auctor sapien volutpat.</p>
<p>
Sed aliquet blandit purus sit amet viverra. Etiam semper, magna ac dapibus luctus, sapien purus vulputate risus, a aliquet magna lorem ac quam. Etiam sagittis pellentesque felis. Ut vitae accumsan mauris, eu facilisis sem. Maecenas viverra commodo odio, sed convallis felis elementum eget. Vivamus imperdiet euismod velit rutrum pulvinar. In gravida nisi tortor, id dignissim nibh malesuada id. Phasellus at commodo neque, pellentesque posuere felis. Mauris sed accumsan tellus, a ultricies est. Quisque arcu sapien, vehicula et eleifend eu, sollicitudin non nibh. Duis in convallis mi. Vivamus ut metus justo. Phasellus pharetra posuere felis eget maximus. Duis ut diam eros.</p>
<p>
Donec consectetur velit ut metus mattis convallis. Nullam eleifend scelerisque diam, vitae pharetra nunc varius et. Sed tortor dui, cursus fringilla maximus non, sollicitudin in justo. Mauris volutpat rutrum nisi, quis condimentum nisi maximus sit amet. Sed vitae lacus sit amet nisi ultrices aliquam. Vestibulum ut aliquet dolor. Aenean ullamcorper mi dolor, vel pharetra justo hendrerit id. Proin condimentum lacinia quam placerat pretium. Duis varius mi eget enim dignissim, vulputate condimentum justo congue. Proin quis interdum nunc. Duis et tellus justo.</p>
<p>
Ut vel nibh in erat cursus maximus a sed nisi. Aliquam vulputate tincidunt est. Praesent euismod nulla eu posuere bibendum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec consectetur est eu felis porttitor hendrerit. Duis sollicitudin, dui pulvinar egestas scelerisque, turpis risus convallis risus, ut pharetra est erat vitae eros. Donec eu metus elementum, viverra nulla et, condimentum risus. Curabitur dapibus aliquet magna ut vestibulum. Donec in dui sit amet risus maximus consectetur.</p>
<p>
Quisque auctor commodo nulla ac condimentum. Duis maximus mauris lacinia malesuada pulvinar. Donec enim nibh, pharetra sed dolor ac, euismod imperdiet felis. Donec a nibh turpis. Nam blandit erat velit, ac rutrum risus dictum ut. Morbi et sollicitudin ligula. Aliquam id libero massa. Proin pellentesque tincidunt volutpat. Curabitur magna erat, auctor a magna vitae, eleifend viverra neque.</p>


<section id="contentId">
Some content far below
</section>


</div>
```

Or, with JS, using the `location.hash` property:

```js
function navigateTo(id) {
  window.location.hash = id;
}
```

```html
<div>

<button type="button" onclick="navigateTo('contentId')">Link to some content</button>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae elit ultrices, ornare metus ac, vehicula magna. Morbi sem metus, vulputate sit amet nunc at, aliquet luctus nisl. Pellentesque congue commodo turpis non luctus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Morbi sed velit et nibh congue faucibus. Suspendisse dapibus leo eget nisl tincidunt placerat. Sed gravida ante quis erat tincidunt, nec auctor sapien volutpat.</p>
<p>
Sed aliquet blandit purus sit amet viverra. Etiam semper, magna ac dapibus luctus, sapien purus vulputate risus, a aliquet magna lorem ac quam. Etiam sagittis pellentesque felis. Ut vitae accumsan mauris, eu facilisis sem. Maecenas viverra commodo odio, sed convallis felis elementum eget. Vivamus imperdiet euismod velit rutrum pulvinar. In gravida nisi tortor, id dignissim nibh malesuada id. Phasellus at commodo neque, pellentesque posuere felis. Mauris sed accumsan tellus, a ultricies est. Quisque arcu sapien, vehicula et eleifend eu, sollicitudin non nibh. Duis in convallis mi. Vivamus ut metus justo. Phasellus pharetra posuere felis eget maximus. Duis ut diam eros.</p>
<p>
Donec consectetur velit ut metus mattis convallis. Nullam eleifend scelerisque diam, vitae pharetra nunc varius et. Sed tortor dui, cursus fringilla maximus non, sollicitudin in justo. Mauris volutpat rutrum nisi, quis condimentum nisi maximus sit amet. Sed vitae lacus sit amet nisi ultrices aliquam. Vestibulum ut aliquet dolor. Aenean ullamcorper mi dolor, vel pharetra justo hendrerit id. Proin condimentum lacinia quam placerat pretium. Duis varius mi eget enim dignissim, vulputate condimentum justo congue. Proin quis interdum nunc. Duis et tellus justo.</p>
<p>
Ut vel nibh in erat cursus maximus a sed nisi. Aliquam vulputate tincidunt est. Praesent euismod nulla eu posuere bibendum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec consectetur est eu felis porttitor hendrerit. Duis sollicitudin, dui pulvinar egestas scelerisque, turpis risus convallis risus, ut pharetra est erat vitae eros. Donec eu metus elementum, viverra nulla et, condimentum risus. Curabitur dapibus aliquet magna ut vestibulum. Donec in dui sit amet risus maximus consectetur.</p>
<p>
Quisque auctor commodo nulla ac condimentum. Duis maximus mauris lacinia malesuada pulvinar. Donec enim nibh, pharetra sed dolor ac, euismod imperdiet felis. Donec a nibh turpis. Nam blandit erat velit, ac rutrum risus dictum ut. Morbi et sollicitudin ligula. Aliquam id libero massa. Proin pellentesque tincidunt volutpat. Curabitur magna erat, auctor a magna vitae, eleifend viverra neque.</p>


<section id="contentId">
Some content far below
</section>


</div>
```